# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setPDFPage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance when integrating ZoomingPDFViewer

Tags: xcode5, unrecognized-selector, pdfviewer

Just wanted to know if anyone can help me fix an issue with ZoomingPDFViewer. For some reason it seems my view is not working even though this is declared correctly (AFAIK).

The only difference I can see is the connections inspector in my app looks like this:
[image: MyApp connections inspector]

and the connections inspector in the example app looks like this:

[image: example app connections inspector]

Does anyone know if this could be a problem? and if it is a problem, can anyone tell me how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for anyone else having this issue, I have found the solution.

It turns out that to make this work correctly, I had to set both the UIview AND the UIScrollView to the same customClass PDFScrollView. So before you put the UIScrollView into the view, you need to set the UIView Class to PDFScrollView in the Identity Inpector. You then need to add your UIScrollView, and set the same PDFScrollView class in the Identity Inspector.

The UIViewController still needs to be given the customClass of ZoomingPDFViewerViewController

Once I did this, it worked well displaying the PDF.

Cheers